# how to redirect index.html to main url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I access my site via `www.domain.com/index.php` or `www.domain.com/index.html`, it needs to redirect to `www.domain.com` for SEO purposes.

How do I configure this in .htaccess?

Comment: If you don’t link to these resources yourself, chances are that search engines will not even find them. And anyway, redirecting is not really necessary – just give the desired “real” address with a `<link rel="canonical" …>`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(index)|(home)(..{3,4})?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)+ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```